# Why mPDF-generated PDF file always saves as 'mpdf.pdf'

Tags: php, mpdf

On my website I generate PDF documents using mPDF library.
They all have rewritten links, like:

http://viled.net/en/datasheet/viled-ss-01-v-s-28-59559560-4-0-43.pdf

When I'm generating PDF, I use SetTitle method:

```
$this->pdf->setTitle($itemTitle);
```

But, when browser trying to save downloaded PDF, it always offer 'mpdf' file name.

How to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What headers do you use when sending the PDF to the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$mpdf->Output('pdf_name.pdf', 'D');
// here D means download pdf directly, you can use I or F also.
```